# How to use keep-alive on routed comps separately in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I've got a question about keep-alive in vue-router. I want to create a list-detail structured app, so I need to refresh the detail comp every time but keep the scroll position of the list comp. As the list comp and the detail comp are under different routes, I don't know how to solve this. If I add keep-alive to `router-view`, they both keep their scroll position, which I don't want the detail comp todo.

Route map looks like below. `SongList` is the list comp and `Learderboard` is the detail comp

```
router.map({
    '/':                    {
        component: Home
    },
    '/songs':               {
        component: SongList
    },
    '/leaderboard/:songId': {
        component: Leaderboard
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: can you post parent component?

Comment: Well how about saving the scroll position of list page in state?

Answer (score 1):

Is it correct that your scroll position is already saved just by using `<keep-alive>`, and you'd like to disable it for a specific component? My scroll position was lost when my component was switched out, even when `<keep-alive>` was present. In order to keep my scroll position I used `<keep-alive>` in combination with a directive plugin called vue-keep-scroll. [My 2.0 fork](https://github.com/okwme/vue-keep-scroll) is still a PR but is working for me. If you only need it for Vue 1.0 you can use the [original here](https://github.com/mark-hahn/vue-keep-scroll).

If your situation is like mine where no scroll position is kept at all you could set it up like this:

```
// in main.js using vue-cli with webpack
var vueKeepScroll = require('vue-keep-scroll')
Vue.use(vueKeepScroll)
```

& in my component:

```
<div v-keep-scroll>
  <div v-for='item in list' v-html='content(item)' />
</div>
```

I see there's another plugin on github doing something similar [here](https://github.com/beeplin/vue-keep-scroll-position).

If scroll position is getting saved even after switching between components you could always force a desired position during the mounted event.